# can not start java container with command in dockerfile

Tags: docker

I have an image that is built using this dockerfile.

```
# vi Dockerfile
FROM openjdk:8
COPY . /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
```

I can login to container in interactive mode and type this command that works as expected.

```
 java -jar /usr/src/myapp/dist/some.jar
```

---

But if I add this line to Dockerfile, I get an error:

```
CMD ["/usr/src/myapp/dist/some.jar", "java"] 

docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \" -jar /usr/src/myapp/dist/some.jar\": stat  -jar /usr/src/myapp/dist/some.jar: no such file or directory".
```

How do I add the java command to dockerfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using thus wrongly. It should be

```
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/usr/src/myapp/dist/some.jar"]
```

or

```
CMD java -jar /usr/src/myapp/dist/some.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the same command as you would type in?

```
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/usr/src/myapp/dist/some.jar"]
```